# Asp.net validation error message to change labels text

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I am using asp.net validation controls for validating user input. What i want is to change the label text with the error message generated by the validation control.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Whats your name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="nameB" Width="322px" Height="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="business" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please tell us your name." ControlToValidate="nameBuisness" CssClass="errMsg" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I like the idea, but I'm not sure it can be done using the regular ASP.NET Validation controls. If you are open for solutions using other validation frameworks (such as jQuery Validate, or some other jQuery validation plugin) I could write up an answer on how to do that with your example.

Comment: Hi @TomasLycken I am new to programming so any suggestion and guideline would be great to learn up.Please do show what you are suggesting Thank you.

Comment: After reading the answers by others, I realize what I had in mind doesn't really fit into the WebForms paradigm - I guess I've been doing ASP.NET MVC for too long :P But there are two good suggestions there for you to try out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to handle the submit-button's `OnClientClick`-event and call a javascript function like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayValidationResult() {
        // Do nothing if client validation is not available
        if (typeof (Page_Validators) == "undefined") return;
        var LblName = document.getElementById('LblName');
        var RequiredName = document.getElementById('RequiredName');
        ValidatorValidate(RequiredName);
        if (!RequiredName.isvalid) {
            LblName.innerText = RequiredName.errormessage;
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:Label ID="LblName" runat="server" Text="Whats your name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtNameBusiness" Width="322px" Height="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredName" ValidationGroup="business"
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please tell us your name." ControlToValidate="TxtNameBusiness"
    CssClass="errMsg" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="BtnSumbit" runat="server"  Text="Submit"
    OnClientClick="displayValidationResult()" ValidationGroup="business" />
```

I've used some of the few ASP.NET client validation methods available. I've also renamed your controls to somewhat more meaningful and added a submit-button.

[**ASP.NET Validation in Depth**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx)

Comment: @Raghav: Then set the validator's `Display="None"`, edited my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, by the way what i am trying to achieve is [link](http://www.f-i.com/contact). Is the above approach the optimum most or shall i go for some thing else.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is that you want to do this validation using the built-in ASP.Net validation controls, then you will need to use the ASP.Net CustomValidator control.  This cannot be done using the ASP.Net RequiredFieldValidator control.  To do the validation you specified, put a CustomValidator control on on your page so that the markup looks like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Whats your name"></asp:Label>

<asp:TextBox ID="nameB" Width="322px" Height="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="nameB" 
    ValidateEmptyText="true"  ErrorMessage="Please tell us your name."  
    onservervalidate="CustValidator_ServerValidate" Display="none"  >**</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click"  CausesValidation="true"  />
```

You then need to write your custom validator.  The server-side validation code looks like this:

```
    protected void CustValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Value))
        {
            Label1.Text = CustValidator.ErrorMessage;
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Whats your name";
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
```

This custom validator will give you the behavior you desire.

In general when you use a CustomValidator control, you should do both server-side validation (for security) and client-side validation (for a better UI experience). To get client-side validation, you will need to write a client-side function in javascript and/or jQuery to do similar validation and then assign it to the ClientValidationFunction of the custom validator.

Further information on the CustomValidator control can be found in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx).

Comment: Hi @Joe Alfano, thanks but there is a issue/ If i am removing the two astriks in the above code the error message is being displayed twice.

By the way here is what i want to achieve, 
[link](http://www.f-i.com/contact)

Comment: Set the validators Display property to none. I've edited my answer.